# Why so many assertions? Simple `assert` not enough?

Tags: ruby, testing

I have no idea why Rails and test frameworks following JUnit's style give us so many assertion types. For example, I can't find a reason to use `assert_equal`; what's the point of using it if you can do `assert expected == actual`? Isn't simple `assert` enough for most (if not all) of the patterns?

Comment: If anything the assertions for minitest are very sparse compared to other test frameworks in other languages like for example [this monster](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/assertions.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what's the point of using `assert_equal` if you can do `assert expected == actual`

Better failure messages, if nothing else. Compare "Expected nil to equal 'foo'" and "Expected false to be true".

(*don't know minitest, but this is how rspec would report the failed expectations*)